# How do you show a set is dense? For example, is the set of all rational numbers ${p \over q}$ with $q ≤ 10$ a dense set?

Tags: analysis

How do you show a set is dense? For example, is The set of all ration numbers ${p \over q}$ with $q ≤  10, p \in \Bbb Z, q \in \Bbb N$ a dense set?

I know that a set is considered dense in $\Bbb R$ if an element of the set can be found between any two real numbers ($a<b$), but I am not sure how to prove this for any given set?

Comment: If you restrict $q$ to be smaller than $10$, how close could you for example approximate $0.15$ in the best case?

Answer (score 1):

For any distinct $\frac pq$ and $\frac{p'}{q'}$ with $q,q'\le N$ the difference
$$ \frac pq-\frac{p'}{q'}=\frac{pq'-p'q}{qq'}$$
is a fraction with non-zero(!) numerator and denominator$\le N^2$, hence is $\ge \frac1{N^2}$ in absolute value.

Comment: What does this information tell me?

Comment: It is the minimal distance between two numbers of your set. What would you expect for a dense set?

Comment: @user310160 Between the numbers $\frac 01$ and $\frac 1N$ ther can be (at most) $N-1$ numbers with denominator $\le N$. Hence between any two consecutive of this finite set there is none, thus showung that the set is not dense

Comment: @k1next, The minimal distance can't be finite for this case. Correct ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, For this case between $[0,1]$ there is finite number of rationals. Hence, the set is not dense. Why ? There can be only 10 divisions between $[0,1]$ as $q \le 10$. Correct ? Why in the proof of yours numerator is $ \le N^2$. The final conclusion $ \ge 1/N^2 $ why ?

Answer (score 0):

In [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) I'm familiar with, a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is *dense in* $X$ iff each $x\in X$ is the limit of some sequence in $A$. Suppose sequences $\left( a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\,\left( b_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ have respective limits $a,\,b\in \mathbb{R}$; then $\delta_n := a_n - b_n$ has limit $a - b$. If $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, arbitrarily small $\delta > 0$ can be expressed in the form $a - b$, so nonzero differences between elements of $A$ must be arbitrarily small. But as Hagen von Eitzen's answer points out, the set you ask about only allows positive gaps $\geq \frac{1}{100}$. So no, it's not dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You are referring to "$X$ is dense in $Y$", while the OP seems to refer to "$X$ is densely ordered" (though not consistently so). For example $\Bbb Q\setminus [0,1]$ is densely ordered, but not dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: In that case, the answer is still no. The set of interest may be written as $\frac{1}{10!}S,\,\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. Since the least two positive elements of $S$ divide by $10!$ to give the least two positive elements of the set of interest, no intermediate elements can exist.

Answer (score 0):

For your set $X = \{p/q\in \mathbb{Q}:\, p, q\in \mathbb{Z}\text{ with }1\leq q\leq 10\}$, the intersection $X\cap [0, 1]$ is finite (and thus closed) and hence not dense in $[0, 1]$.